# A medical checkup/medical check-ups

Tags: word-choice

If I am talking about several checkups can I use the second  sentence below or does the singular form, if I use it will be understood as only one  checkup which doesn't involve more than one.

1. "I went for medical checkups last time on Monday."

Or

2. "I went for a  medical checkup last time on Monday."

Comment: When you say 'several check-ups', do you mean that several different tests were done during the same visit? Unless you want your hearers to know all the details, I think it would be normal to call the whole event 'a medical check-up'.

Comment: Yes, when  a person does several different tests and sees different doctors.